# GPO - Disable Lock Screen & Display turn off after 15 min

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

we have Windows Server with AD.
After 15 minutes of inactivity the computer screen turns off and the computer locks.

I want to turn this off, I want the computer to work always in display mode even when not in use
I Created new GPO Policy with the following settings:
Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit: Enabled-  0
Do not display the lock screen : Enabled - 0

And i also created  power plan from GPO with this settings: https://ibb.co/5THFpTg

what am I missing? Why is the computer still locked after 15 minutes?
Thanks.

Comment: you needed to clean up the gpo cache manually. after this run `rsop` on the client and see what gpo are affected.

Comment: Hi Djdomi, Thanks for answer.
I tried to Reset PC completely.
changed to WORKGROUP and then back to DC. 
GPUpdate /force , gpresult scope-computer to make sure policy applied. 
I also added 'prevent change desktop background' policy to make sure that it works. and its works. but the computer still locked and turn black after 15 min.

Comment: IMHO, you may do not delete the cache. (%windir%\system32\GroupPolicy)
Remind, that the Energy-Saving settings could also affect this. As Also, remind, as long as the Computer might be influenced by the other GPO - a Restrict goes before Allow. And as a Feature - did you rebooted windows 3 times afterwards? (Most Admis does not even know about this windows "Feature" in case of GPO issues...)